# How to add new property to application.yml file

Tags: amazon-web-services, spring-cloud, spring-cloud-stream

I am working taking help from the following project:

https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-samples/tree/master/kinesis-samples/kinesis-produce-consume

The following is the application.yml code snippet :

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        ordersOut: 
          destination: test_stream
          content-type: application/json
          producer: 
            partitionKeyExpression: "1" 
        ordersIn:
          destination: test_stream
          content-type: application/json
```

If I want to have include `autoAddShards`, `minShardCount` properties where to add it.

Answer (score 0):

According AWS Kinesis Binder [Documentation](https://github.com/spring-cloud/spring-cloud-stream-binder-aws-kinesis/blob/master/spring-cloud-stream-binder-kinesis-docs/src/main/asciidoc/overview.adoc#configuration-options) we have:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      kinesis:
        binder:
          autoAddShards: true
          minShardCount: 10
```

Answer (score 0):

Complete config file:

```
spring:
  cloud:
    stream:
      bindings:
        ordersOut: 
          destination: test_stream
          content-type: application/json
          producer: 
            partitionKeyExpression: "1" 
        ordersIn:
          destination: test_stream
          content-type: application/json
      kinesis:
        binder:
          auto-add-shards: true
          min-shard-count:  10
```

Comment: Could you provide the versions for which this config is working?

Comment: For this version: 2.0.4.RELEASE